# Is Transmission Control Protocol of in a tamper proof (by 'tiny' explosions) device not the only way to circumvent transport correlation attacks?

Tags: anonymity, security, ip-address, traffic-analysis, time

[Goal](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/263758/how-does-tor-play-the-role-of-dns): I am trying to build an anonymous voting system and am wondering if Tor is sufficient to anonymize data by command-run-on(s), only when the proxy-onion-node has encrypted IP addresses that are destroyed upon opening/tampering?

Pain Point: traffic correlation/metadata PII+vote sent by cron job still defeats anonymity if correlated by timestamp of milliseconds or less certainly.

Solution: To prevent access to routing with tiny 'explosions' that destroy IP addresses to not only (1) prevent reuse+tapping but hide (2) addresses. **The private key that encrypts the addresses may have to be 'hard-coded' and generated randomly**.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough for your task. Tor hides the one **who is requesting** the data, not the one who is serving it. But in your case you're already open just by proposing a voting process, so it's totally not a concern in any matters. And - yes - Tor will shield up your voters

Comment: Hey Alexey - I am not open as a voting process for the audit is merely matching the size of a dataset of public ID profiles and their anonymized votes (cron trigger jobs first and last). "**Personally Identifiable Information (PII)+vote**." More than several months ago, here, is [alpha](https://github.com/NickCarducci/Wavepoint.la/blob/master/src/components/Post/VoteModule.js), for posterity not advertisement (et what is the difference). Probably not working but that is what waterfalled so far.